# Memory leak in my javascript app

Tags: javascript, memory, knockout.js, memory-leaks

I am new to javascript/html app development. I have page1 with a button when clicked takes me to page2. Every time I go to page1 to page2 and then navigate back to page1 there is a 10 MB increased in memory usage and it keeps increasing as I use it. Here is the pattern of page1.

Here is the code for Page1viewModel.js

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};

var Page1ViewModel = (function (_super) {
    "use strict";

    __extends(ViewModel, _super);
    >>>>
    some variables declared here
    >>>>

    function ViewModel(modelParameter) {
        _super.call(this, modelParameter);
        var self = this;
    >>>>
    some code here
    >>>>
        this.unloaded(false);
    };

    // Observable to tell the view when the page has been unloaded.
    ViewModel.prototype.unloaded = ko.observable(false);

    // Method that is called on the app exiting this page.
    ViewModel.prototype.unload = function () {
    <<<code to remove handlers>>>>
        this.unloaded(true);
    };

   <<< some more prototype functions>>>

    return ViewModel;
})(BaseViewModel);
```

And here is the code for Page1.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var viewModel,
        view;
    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/Page1.html", {
        ready: function (element, options) {

            viewModel = new Page1ViewModel(window.appModel);
            view = new Page1View(element, viewModel);

            ko.applyBindings(view, element.children[0]);

            view.initialize();
        },
        unload: function (element) {
            view.unload();
            viewModel.unload();
        }

    });
})();
```

Is there anything evidently wrong with this pattern?

Comment: Is it Windows 8 Store App? You can try to use JavaScript Memory Analysis tool which is available from VS 2012 Update 1.

Comment: Yes I already tried that.... I see that for some reason, the memory usage shown on the tool is very different from what I see in the task manager and I was not able to arrive any conclusive reason for the memory leak'

Comment: The problem is that in the tools when I tale a heap snap shot of page2, the ViewModel of page1 is still showing up. Is it not supposed to be disposed?

Comment: So looks like this is memory leak which you are looking for. Check who is taking the reference to this ViewModel.